# Не могу разобраться что не так с запросом к БД, боюсь что много что не так

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите люди добрые, не могу понять что тут да как в php, на мой взгляд вроде все нормально, но увы...

Ошибок не выдает, подключается, работает в общем как надо, но результат пустой... я его наверное запрашиваю не правильно?

```
<?
$host       = "localhost";
$dbuser     = "***user***";
$dbpass     = "***pass***";
$db         = "***mydb***";
$id = $_POST['id']; 
$link = mysql_connect($host, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Error connect!"); 
mysql_select_db($db, $link); 

if (!empty($id))
{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id LIKE " + $id;
    $data = mysql_query($sql);
    $res = mysql_result($data);
    echo  $res;
    echo  $data;
}
else 
{
    echo "Empty id";
}
?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($sql);` для начала. потом [сюда](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: А у вас id что ли строковый и вы ищете кусок этой строки ? по крайней мере like предназначен именно для этого. А для выборки по числовым полям да и просто на равенство испоьзуется оператор равно. `where id=xx`

Comment: Ну и разумеется положенные разглагольствования о том что по этому коду все SQL инъекции плачут и что функцию mysql_query вообще-то уже запретили использовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Действительно, здесь очень много что не так. Основных проблем три

1. Неверный синтаксис РНР. + не объединяет строки. для этого служит точка.
2. В любом случае, с помощью конкатенации запросы собирать нельзя. Чтобы избежать множества проблем, включая SQL инъекции, надо использовать в запросе подстановки.
3. Использование несуществующих функций языка.

Правильно будет делать запрос с использованием [ПДО](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo)

```
<?
$host       = "localhost";
$dbuser     = "***user***";
$dbpass     = "***pass***";
$db         = "***mydb***";
$charset    = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass, $opt);
// все что выше этой строки надо вынести в отдельный файл 
// и подключать через include

if (!empty($_POST['id']))
{
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->execute([$_POST['id']]);
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    var_dump($row);
}
else 
{
    echo "Empty id";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за код и особенно за ссылку... Мне надо взять за правило прежде чем что то читать и изучать, смотреть на год статьи)

Comment: Да, это очень хорошее правило, кстати